# What is Apache's other_vhosts_access.log file used for?

Tags: apache, nginx, virtual-machine, virtualhost

What is Apache's other_vhosts_access.log file used for?

I cannot find any documentation on this file on Google.

On the local system, which runs both Apache and Nginx, a lot of entries are displayed in `other_vhosts_access.log`, like:

```
kr.b19cms.dk:80 127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jun/2018:08:46:30 +0200] "POST /CHANGELOG.txt HTTP/1.0" 200 108893 "-" "drupalgeddon2" 246.189.151.79, 127.0.0.1
```

However, I cannot seem to make much out of it?

Comment: Is this question about Apache or `nginx`? The example looks like an `nginx` log entry, but `nginx` logfile names can be `anything_you_want.log` - the only way to know for sure, is to look in the configuration file(s) and find out where it's defined.

Comment: @RichardSmith - The entry is from the `other_vhosts_access.log` log.

Comment: `other_vhosts_access.log` contains logs of VirtualHosts that don't have their own log file defined. You can check the configuration in the `/etc/apache2/conf-available/other-vhosts-access-log.conf` file.

Answer (score 5):

Usually one of the vhosts is marked as default - so if the `Host:` HTTP header does not match any of the other vhosts then the default vhost will be used to handle the request.
However, if no vhost is marked as default - then it goes into this log.